# Регулярное выражение для проверки имени срабатывает выборочно

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть проверка на валидность имени (например Иванов И. И.):

```
    if(preg_match("/^[А-яіїІЇёЁ. ']+$/", $text)) echo "ОК";
    else echo "не правильно";
```

Здесь все буквы кириллицы от большой "А" и до маленькой "я" + украинское большое и маленькое "і" + русское больше и маленькое "ё" + пробел + точка + украинский апостроф (одинарная кавычка).
Проблема в том, что когда:

```
 $text = "Василий В. І."; // работает
 $text = "Иванов В. Ё.";  // работает
```

а вот так:

```
$text = "Проба И. М.";  //не работает
```

Почему?

Comment: попробуйте `А-Яа-яіїІЇёЁ. '`

Comment: Спасибо, что отозвались, но не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно у вас текст в кодировке UTF-8, добавьте модификатор регулярного выражения u

```
<?php
$text = "Проба И. М.";
if(preg_match("/^[А-яіїІЇёЁ. ']+$/u", $text)) echo "ОК";
else echo "не правильно";
```

Comment: все верно, спасибо огромное